# SVG (Python) xPath get Elements by Attribute

Tags: python, xpath, svg, lxml

Hello im making a programm to IMPORT a SVG File into my Document. (LXML)

```
    if so.funktion != "0":
        if so.funktion=="1":
            searchStr = '//svg:g[@svg-creator="popup1"]'
            selectStr = template.xpath(searchStr, namespaces=inkex.NSS)
            if selectStr != []:
                selectStr[0].set("id","Popup "+so.name)
                self.current_layer.append(selectStr[0])
            else:
                None
```

My SVG File :

```
<g
 id="p1"
 svg-creator="popup1"
 transform="translate(140,-160)">
<rect
   y="900"
   x="0"
   height="180"
   width="200"
   id="rect6309"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:0.7372549;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1" />
<g
   id="b1234"
   svg-creator="button1">
  <rect
     style="opacity:1;fill:#6c6c6c;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
     id="rect6588"
     width="126"
     height="34"
     x="59"
     y="1023" />
  <text
     sodipodi:linespacing="125%"
     id="text6770"
     y="1045.8575"
     x="91.91333"
     style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:50px;line-height:125%;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     xml:space="preserve"><tspan
       style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:17.5px;font-family:'Franklin Gothic Medium';-inkscape-font-specification:'Franklin Gothic Medium, ';fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1"
       y="1045.8575"
       x="91.91333"
       id="tspan6772"
       sodipodi:role="line">button1</tspan></text>
</g>
<g
   id="b83217"
   transform="translate(0,-50)"
   svg-creator="button2">
  <rect
     style="opacity:1;fill:#6c6c6c;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
     id="rect6588-2"
     width="126"
     height="34"
     x="59"
     y="1023" />
  <text
     sodipodi:linespacing="125%"
     id="text6770-7"
     y="1045.8575"
     x="91.91333"
     style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:50px;line-height:125%;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     xml:space="preserve"><tspan
       style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:17.5px;font-family:'Franklin Gothic Medium';-inkscape-font-specification:'Franklin Gothic Medium, ';fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1"
       y="1045.8575"
       x="91.91333"
       id="tspan6772-6"
       sodipodi:role="line">button2</tspan></text>
</g>
<text
   xml:space="preserve"
   style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:50px;line-height:125%;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
   x="75.460815"
   y="941.51672"
   id="text421312"
   sodipodi:linespacing="125%"
   svg-creator="title"><tspan
     sodipodi:role="line"
     id="tspan8274"
     x="75.460815"
     y="941.51672"
     style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:27.5px;font-family:'Franklin Gothic Medium';-inkscape-font-specification:'Franklin Gothic Medium, ';fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1">Title</tspan></text>
```

I can change and set the Attributes of my svg:g so far, but i need to access/manipulate another svg:g inside that selectStr !

How can i access and manipulate button1 and button2 of that xpath?
(i have multiple popups with same attributes, so my actual xPath contains popup1)

Comment: By applying another XPath on element object returned by your current XPath. I'm afraid no more specific explanation can be provided unless you also provide more specific information i.e sample XML that include currently selected element, and the actual target element. Thanks

Comment: Sure heres the code:

Comment: What are you trying to change?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple XPath to find child element, for example, "button1" from `selectStr` :

```
btn1 = selectStr.find('svg:g[@svg-creator="button1"]', inkex.NSS)
```

or using `xpath()` method if you like :

```
btn1 = selectStr.xpath('svg:g[@svg-creator="button1"]', namespaces=inkex.NSS)[0]
```